# Mat-table with rowGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my [Mat-table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) I need to display a result like the picture below, with a row that specify a specific property of the items.

I am following this example:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-with-groupheader?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts) but in my case I am comparing the current item property with the precedent one and if these properties are not the same I need to show the rowGroup
I don't know if it is the correct way with material but in the method that do this comparsion I am not be able to get the precedent item.

**Method**

```
isGroup(index, item: AccessLog): boolean {
  if (index == null) return false;
    if (this.accesslogs && this.accesslogs.length > 0) {
      if (index == 0) return true;
      else {
        if (item.remoteAddress == this.accesslogs[index - 1].remoteAddress) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Html**

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="accesslogs" class="example-table" matSort (matSortChange)="temp($event)">
    <!-- Number Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="createdDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ "accesslogs.table.headers.createddate" | translate }}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.createdDate | date: ("pattern.datehourmin" | translate) }}</td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="remoteAddress">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ "accesslogs.table.headers.remoteaddress" | translate }}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.remoteAddress }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Created Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>{{ "accesslogs.table.headers.useragent" | translate }}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.userAgent | ellipse: 50 }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

    <!-- Group header -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="groupHeader">
      <td colspan="999" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <strong>ip {{ row.remoteAddress }}</strong>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['groupHeader']; when: isGroup"></tr>
  </table>
```

[image: rowgroup]

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Or what do you mean by can't get the precedent item?

Comment: @FabianKüng when I try to access to the array accesslogs (this.accesslogs[index - 1]) is always undefined

Comment: Can you post the code how/when the array `accesslogs` gets populated? If you debug through the code, is `this.accesslogs` actually populated in this `if (item.remoteAddress == this.accesslogs[index - 1].remoteAddress)` statement? Quite difficult to troublehshoot without more information on your data.

Comment: Could you had more info to the post? Like how it's populated for example? Or make an stackblitz with the code you have? With only this information it's complicated to see something...

Comment: @FabianKüng access log is populated with an http request, and it works properly

Comment: I played around with it a bit and it seems the `when` function that is executed to decide whether a grouped row should be displayed or not runs in its own context and not in your component context, so accessing `this.accesslogs` will always be undefined.

Comment: I created a quick and dirty [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-with-groupheader-wpuo8u?file=app/table-basic-example.ts) which should solve your problem. Basically it sorts/prepares the data you get from your async call (simulated with RxJS) so it is ready to display and your `when` function only has to do a minimal check whether or not to display a group row.

Comment: Thank you, so we must manipulate the original array to achieve this...I hope material can implement a better way but for now it works good